# How to get value of Expression<Action<T>> action quickly?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

Suppose we have the following code:

```
ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression<AccountController>(ax => ax.MyAction("a", "b"));
```

(from ASP.NET MVC Futures assembly). Method is reasonably fast - it executes 10k iterations in 150ms.

Now, we change code to this:

```
string a = "a";
string b = "b";
ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression<AccountController>(ax => ax.MyAction(a, b));
```

This code will execute 10k iterations in 15 **seconds**

The problem is the following code:

```
Expression<Func<object>> lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Convert(arg, typeof (object)));

Func<object> func = lambdaExpression.Compile();

value = func()
```

Is there a better way to get value from expression than compiling expression every time? This can greatly affect ASP.NET MVC link generation speed.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just cache the value of the expression and its compiled value locally if this is such a bottleneck? I imagine a simply Dictionary could do the trick:

```
Dictionary<Expression<Action<T>>, Action<T>> m_Cache =
    new Dictionary<Expression<Action<T>>, Action<T>>();

public void GetRouteValuesFromExpression<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expr) {
    Action<T> compiled = null;
    if (!m_Cache.TryGetValue(expr, ref compiled)) {
        compiled = expr.Compile();
        m_Cached.Add(expr, compiled);
    }
    // execute …
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. Expression doesn't contain values if they are not constant. So, in my example above, you would end up caching one link for all possible values of a and b.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, I didn't realize the values were changing, which is kinda stupid on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a `Func<object>`? You could probably manually craft a "capture" - i.e. have a type that declares a & b; have a `Func<Whatever, object>`, and compile this to a delegate. Then all you do at runtime is:

```
Foo foo = new Foo {A = a, B = b};
return cachedFunc(foo);
```

I'm not quite sure what the Convert(blah, typeof(object)) is doing - can you clarify this? I've got quite a bit of experience with expressions, but this seems... unusual...

Comment: This is code from ASP.NET MVC futures assembly and the same code is used in Moq to get value of parametres, so I guess this is the "official way" of doing it. I am asking this question because this behaveour reduces number of request in our web site by factor 2.5...

Answer (score 0):

I've fiddled for a bit and came up with the following:

```
var body = (MethodCallExpression)expr.Body;
var arg1 = (MemberExpression)body.Arguments[0];
var contextType = arg1.Member.DeclaringType;
var field = contextType.GetField(arg1.Member.Name);
Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(…));
```

Assuming that `expr` is your `Expression<Action<T>>` argument, this gives you the reflected field which is passed as the first argument to your call (`a` in your case). However, I wasn't able to extract the context necessary to evaluate this field (last line, location marked by “…”). I believe this context cannot be accessed without compilation of the expression. As a consequence, what you want isn't possible.

*Please* prove me wrong. ;-)

(Actually, I'm not really sure because even using the Reflector I'm unable to find where the execution context is being stored so I might overlook something.)